# What is the purpose of repurposing electronic signs?

Tags: watch-dogs

In Watch Dogs, there are electronic signs that can be hacked. Doing so displays funny messages on them, such as:

> ITS OVER 9000!!!

or

> YO DAWG I HERD YOU LIKE SIGNS

I was wondering if - aside from the quotes and memes - there was any reason to hack those signs. It doesn't look like the world reacts to them in any way.

What is the purpose of those signs?

Comment: They don't serve a purpose.  They are just something to hack while your driving.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hacking the signs doesn't do anything of consequence. Nearby pedestrians may react to a sign being hacked.